# Checking the opening of an attribute table with pyqgis

Tags: pyqgis, attribute-table

I know how to show the attribute table of a specific layer (with showAttributeTable), but how to check if the attribute table of a specific layer is already opened ? I don't want to show it again if it's already visible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use something like the following:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication

attrTables = [d for d in QApplication.instance().allWidgets() if d.objectName() in (u'QgsAttributeTableDialog', u'AttributeTable')]
for x in attrTables:
    if 'layerName' in x.windowTitle():
        pass
    else:
        # do something
```

---

**Edit:**

As [@Etienne](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/92626/etienne) mentioned in the comments, you could use the following for a more accurate method of obtaining the attribute table of a specific layer (assuming no layers have duplicate names):

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication

attrTables = [d for d in QApplication.instance().allWidgets() if d.objectName() in (u'QgsAttributeTableDialog', u'AttributeTable')]
for x in attrTables: 
    w_title = x.windowTitle() 
    tab_lyr = w_title[:w_title.index("::")-1]
    if tab_lyr == 'layer_name':
        # do something
```

Comment: Thanks, it works correctly, but I will add this to be sure to find the right attribute-table:
'for x in attrTables:
    w_title = x.windowTitle()
    tab_lyr = w_title[:w_title.index("::")-1]
    if tab_lyr == 'layer_name':
 # do something'

Comment: @Etienne - Most welcome and yes, that is a more accurate way :)

Comment: Note that in QGIS 3, PyQGIS uses PyQt5 and QApplication is now within the `PyQt5.QtWidgets` module. You can then replace the import statement by `from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29260064/11896053).

Comment: @onietosi - Thanks for the update.