# Checking if attribute table is showed on the screen with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, pyqt

I'm using the code in this question ([Checking the opening of an attribute table with pyqgis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/270873/checking-the-opening-of-an-attribute-table-with-pyqgis/270874#270874)) to check if there are attribute table open in QGIS. More precisely, I need to check if some attribute tables is showed on the screen. 
Unfortunately using this code `tab_lyr`is always different from `'layer_name'` because in `tab_lyr` there's always a space in front the real layer name. For example: `' layer_name'`.
Where's the problem?

```
attrTables = [d for d in QApplication.instance().allWidgets() if d.objectName() in (u'QgsAttributeTableDialog', u'AttributeTable')]
for x in attrTables: 
    w_title = x.windowTitle() 
    tab_lyr = w_title[:w_title.index("::")-1]
    if tab_lyr == 'layer_name':
```

I tried `if len(attrTables)>0` but the length of attrTables can be > 0 also if there are not attribute tables shown.

This code seems to work except in some cases I haven’t figured out yet

```
 attrTables = [d for d in QApplication.instance().allWidgets() if d.objectName() in (u'QgsAttributeTableDialog', u'AttributeTable')]
      if len(attrTables)>0:
        for x in attrTables: 
          w_title = x.windowTitle() 
          tab_lyr = w_title[:w_title.index("::")].strip()
          print(tab_lyr)
          if tab_lyr == layer1.name():
            pass
          elif tab_lyr == layer2.name(): 
            pass
          else:
            attDialog=iface.showAttributeTable(layer1)
            attDialog.findChild(QAction,'mActionSelectedFilter').trigger()
            attDialog2=iface.showAttributeTable(layer2)
            attDialog2.findChild(QAction,'mActionSelectedFilter').trigger()   
      else: 
        attDialog=iface.showAttributeTable(layer1)
        attDialog.findChild(QAction,'mActionSelectedFilter').trigger()
        attDialog2=iface.showAttributeTable(layer2)
        attDialog2.findChild(QAction,'mActionSelectedFilter').trigger()
```

Comment: When and how do you call your function? What is Library()? This function seems to do the opposite of what you want: it opens an attribute table only if another one is already open.

Comment: Ok, I corrected (sorry aboyt Library(), it was a typo it does not mean anything)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the attribute dialog window title just so happens to contain a space before the layer name

```
 >>> w_title
 ' layer_name :: Features Total:...'
```

When you slice it with `w_title[:w_title.index("::")]`, you keep the first blank character.

Just use `strip`. Without arguments, `strip` removes whitespace characters from the start and the end of your string

```
tab_lyr = w_title[:w_title.index("::")].strip()
```

To answer to the second part of your question, your poblem is that when you have only one atttribute table opened (either layer1 or layer2), you never open the other. Here is a more generic solution. If you need to handle more layers, just replace `(layer1, layer2)` with `(layer1, layer2, layer3, ...)` and so on.

```
attribute_table_titles = [
    d.windowTitle()
    for d in QApplication.instance().allWidgets()
    if d.objectName() in (u"QgsAttributeTableDialog", u"AttributeTable")
]

already_open_layers = [
    title[: title.index("::")].strip() for title in attribute_table_titles
]

for layer in (layer1, layer2):
    if layer.name() not in already_open_layers:
        attDialog = iface.showAttributeTable(layer)
        attDialog.findChild(QAction, "mActionSelectedFilter").trigger()
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer! Can you check my edit?

Comment: It works very well, thanks!